# Comparison table for subelements

Tags: tables, interface, tabs, comparison

Can you please help me determine which comparison design is better for UX?
I have documents with elements. Every element has 5 attributes. I need to compare those attributes across 3 to 5 documents. Number of elements can be max 10 for one document.

I try 2 designs for simple comparing feature.

- This one as whole table: https://jsfiddle.net/bpavol/potzm2sx/5/
- And second one as toggable tabs: https://jsfiddle.net/bpavol/9xrk6pzv/4/

Which one will be better for UX? Or should I use something completely different?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second version by far. The user has more control over functionality and can reach relevant information faster and easier!